# Built-in XML functions

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g, xml

I am trying to use built-in XML functions, but I'm getting an `%s: invalid identifier` error. Selects works fine without the XML functions.

Any ideas where is the mistake?

```
select id,full_name from users where id in(
with sample_data as
(
 (select pm_id 
 from pm  where p_id=30369)
)
select cast(t.column_value.extract('//text()') as varchar2(40)) val
  from sample_data,
  table( xmlsequence( xmltype(
    '<x><x>' || replace(pm_id, '#@#', '</x><x>') || '</x></x>'
  ).extract('//x/*'))) t)
```

Comment: What oracle version?

Comment: the version is 11g

Comment: Can you at least try and execute it in SQL developer or sql plus? It'll tell you where the error is

Comment: sql exception:
ORA-04023: Object could not be validated or authorized

Comment: I got this error. in sql plus. And in sql developer it says it is the first line

Comment: Actually, not sure you're allowed a WITH clause inside an IN

Comment: Does it not give an object name in the ORA-04023 message? It should do.

Comment: as object name it gives the hole code.

Answer (score 2):

@elimerv,

Are you sure you are not having something else in place of "single-quote" that is expected there? Also, you don't tell what kind of data does the "pm" table has in the pm_id column (BTW, your latest SQL doesn't appear to be correct as your sample_data subquery has an "id" column whereas your main query refers to "pm_id" column).
This is what I get on 11.2.0.1
First, your latest query, as it is (except for tables used):

```
with sample_data as (
   select '123#@#' id
   from dual
  )
  select sysdate from dual where dummy  in(
    select cast(t.column_value.extract('//text()') as varchar2(400)) val
    from sample_data,
         table(xmlsequence(xmltype('<x><x>'||replace(pm_id,'#@#','</x><x>')||'</x></x>').extract('//x/*'))) t
  )
 10  /
         table(xmlsequence(xmltype('<x><x>'||replace(pm_id,'#@#','</x><x>')||'</x></x>').extract('//x/*'))) t
                                                     *
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00904: "PM_ID": invalid identifier
```

Now, with correct column name used:

```
with sample_data as (
   select '123#@#' pm_id
   from dual
  )
  select sysdate from dual where dummy  in(
    select cast(t.column_value.extract('//text()') as varchar2(400)) val
    from sample_data,
         table(xmlsequence(xmltype('<x><x>'||replace(pm_id,'#@#','</x><x>')||'</x></x>').extract('//x/*'))) t
  )
 10  /

no rows selected
```

And, when I replaced one of the "single-quotes" with a different (but similar looking) character :

```
with sample_data as (
   select '123#@#' pm_id
   from dual
  )
  select sysdate from dual where dummy  in(
    select cast(t.column_value.extract('//text()') as varchar2(400)) val
    from sample_data,
         table(xmlsequence(xmltype('<x><x>'||replace(pm_id,'#@#','</x><x>')||'</x></x>').extract(`//x/*'))) t
  )
 10  /
         table(xmlsequence(xmltype('<x><x>'||replace(pm_id,'#@#','</x><x>')||'</x></x>').extract(`//x/*'))) t
                                                                                                 *
ERROR at line 8:
ORA-00911: invalid character
```

Does this give you any idea?
BTW, are you sure you need XML processing to solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I think Phil is on the right track. You need to move the CTE ("WITH clause") out of the sub-select

Try this one:

```
with sample_data as (
 select pm_id 
 from pm  
 where p_id=30369
)
select id,
       full_name 
from users 
where id in(
  select cast(t.column_value.extract('//text()') as varchar2(40)) val
  from sample_data,
       table(xmlsequence(xmltype('<x><x>'||replace(pm_id,'#@#','</x><x>')||'</x></x>').extract('//x/*'))) t
)
```

Comment: Thanks your reply but no luck, got the same error

Comment: Edit your answer with the full error messages when run through sqlplus. Cut and paste the query and EVERYTHING up to where the SQL> prompt returns after the message.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQL> with sample_data as (
  2   select  id
  3   from pm
  4   where p_id=30369
  5  )
  6  select id, full_name from users where id  in(
  7    select cast(t.column_value.extract('//text()') as varchar2(400)) val
  8    from sample_data,
  9         table(xmlsequence(xmltype('<x><x>'||replace(pm_id,'#@#','</x><x>')||'</x></x>').extract('//x/*'))) t
 10  )
 11  /
       table(xmlsequence(xmltype('<x><x>'||replace(pm_id,'
#@#','</x><x>')||'</x></x>').extract('//x/*'))) t
                                     *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier


SQL>
```

Comment: I got the above error